# Polsarpro with ActiveTCL but error comming missing in expressing

Tags: tcl

I want to run "Polsarpro" with ActiveTCL.

But after running PolSARpro_v4.2.0 program this error is coming:

```
missing “
in expressing “$lettre ==”\””
(parsing expressing  “$lettre ==”\””)
Invoke from within 
“if {“$lettre ==”\””} {set  lettre ==”/””}’
(procedure “InitPolSARproENV” line 30)
Invoked from within
“InitPolSARproEnv”
(procedure “init” line 521)
Invoked from within 
“init $argc $argv”
(file “C:\program Files\Files\PolSARpro_v4.2\PolSARpro_v4.2.0.tcl”line
12328)
```

What I have to do to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm betting that the character in use is `"` and not `“`; Tcl regards the other as a plain old character that doesn't mean anything…

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
if {"$lettre =="\""} {set  lettre =="/""}
```

Looks like that should be:

```
if { $lettre =="\""} {set  lettre =="/""}
#...^
```

You can use different quotes to reduce the escaping

```
if { $lettre == {"}} {set  lettre =="/""}
```

And if you're comparing strings, use the string equality operator

```
if { $lettre eq {"}} {set  lettre =="/""}
```

The value of the set command looks odd, but it's valid.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the set probably should have been `set lettre "\""`, and recommend the [tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) as a first step for study.